# Sort Google Sheet by order values are entered in a data validation

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to sort a Google Sheet by the order in which values are entered into a data validation criteria?

I want to sort the sheet based in ascending order Low,Medium,High or descending order High,Medium,Low.  Not by alphabetical order High,Low,Medium and Medium,Low,High respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron. The easiest way would be to use a helper column (which you can hide later if you like) wherein you assign numerical values to your Low, Medium and High (presumably 1, 2 and 3 respectively). Then you sort using the numerical column. It's fairly easy to write a one-cell array formula that would assign the numerical values to your labels. The numerical column need not be beside the label column; it can be any column.

Without seeing an actual sample sheet, I can't *show* you. But hopefully the concept is clear, and you can take it from there.

---

Added description after sheet was shared:

In the example sheet, Sheet1 Column A contained the Priority in words (Low, Medium, High) and Column B contained "other data." I placed the following array formula into C1:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Priority Val";IF(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A,Data!A:B,2,FALSE))})
```

The formula is an array formula, hence the ArrayFormula() wrap.

Inside this are curly brackets {} which allow the building of arrays that are not "of a type." In this case, the header is listed first ("Priority Val"). The semicolon means "place the next part underneath." Then a VLOOKUP references every value in Column A (i.e., the priority words) against a simple chart in a second sheet named "Data." In that "Data" sheet, Column A simply lists 1, 2, 3 and Column B lists your exact words: Low, Medium, High. The IF() function just checks to see if a row in Sheet1!A:A is blank. If so, a null is assigned before trying the VLOOKUP; otherwise, every blank row would show an #NA error.

If you want to make it even more air tight, it's good practice to wrap VLOOKUP in IFERROR(), just in case you misspell something in Sheet1!A:A. That would look like this:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Priority Val";IF(A2:A="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)))})
```

And you can avoid misspelling by applying data validation to Sheet1!A2:A, referencing Data!A:A as the only allowable answers. This is not strictly necessary; but I have done it in the sample sheet to show you.

Comment: Hi Erik, I am pretty confused on how to implement your suggestion.  Here is a test [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YfOkp-B5ITCFkN_nWGIZ6DyYGdXNqjPA2_DS1tTjAX0/edit?usp=sharing).  I added a second sheet to store the data used in the data validation

Comment: Aaron, your sheet is currently "View Only." If you set the permission to "Anyone with the link can edit," I can get in and illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Erik, sorry about that.  It should be editable now. Thank you!

Comment: Aaron, I've made changes and added notes into the sheet. I've also updated my original answer above, if you want a full breakdown of how things work. I did not apply sorting to the range; I figured I'd let you do that yourself, so you can see how it works, sorting on Column C. (BTW, if you select entire rows for the sort, just be aware that my Notes cell will also move and may not look as you expect.)

Comment: Thanks Erik, this was very helpful!

Comment: Glad we sorted it out.